# How to pre-select ALL options in a jquery mobile dropdown data-bound by knockout?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

Could someone please show me how to preselect all items in a knockout data-bound select with multiple selection tag set?

I've tried using this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-2.0.0.debug.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
</head>
<body>
Choose a company: <select id="companies" data-role="select" data-bind="options: companies,
optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
optionsText: 'companyName',
optionsValue: 'companyValue',
selectedOptions: chosencompanies" data-native-menu="false" multiple></select> 
<input data-bind="value: chosencompanies"></input>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  function company(name, value) {
      this.name = ko.observable(name);
      this.value = ko.observable(value);
  }
  var viewModel = {
      companies: ko.observableArray([
              { companyName: "test", companyValue: 0 },
              { companyName: "test1", companyValue: 1 },
              { companyName: "test2", companyValue: 2 },
              { companyName: "test5", companyValue: 5 },
              { companyName: "test7", companyValue: 7 },
          ]),
      chosencompanies: ko.observableArray(),
      resetcompanies: function () { this.chosencompanies(null) }
  };
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

  $("#companies option").prop('selected', true);
  $("#companies").selectmenu();
  $("#companies").selectmenu('refresh', 'true');

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even though I'm using *$("#companies option").prop('selected', true)* it seems to **only** affect the visual appearance of the dropdown control and not the data-bound chosenCompanies varialbe which is what I need set? :(whose value you can see also since it is data-bound to the input field beneath the dropdown) And before someone proposes please, I realize that I could initialize the observableArray with a comma separated value list, but what when my selection options are dynamic and I don't know with what values I should preinit the observableArray?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your **select** element binds optionsValue to companyValue, so to preselect the option you should push company values to your choosencompanies array like this:

```
var source = [
              { companyName: "test", companyValue: 0 },
              { companyName: "test1", companyValue: 1 },
              { companyName: "test2", companyValue: 2 },
              { companyName: "test5", companyValue: 5 },
              { companyName: "test7", companyValue: 7 },
          ];

var viewModel = {
      companies: ko.observableArray(source),
      chosencompanies: ko.observableArray([]),
      resetcompanies: function () { this.chosencompanies(null) }     
  };
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {    
   viewModel.chosencompanies.push(source[i].companyValue);
}
```

In this case after initialization all companies will be preselected except "Choose company" and values will be displayed in textbox delimited by coma.